# How do I create a drawable on the fly for a custom list adapter to assign to an imageview?

Tags: android, imageview, drawable, listadapter

I have a column in a database that can be any combination of of the letters `RGBMCY`, `(Red, Green, Blue, Magenta, Cyan, Yellow)`. It can be 1-6 characters long, any order, as long as each letter appears at most 1 time. Something like 720 possible different combinations. It would be very time consuming to create every possibility, plus bloating the APK that much more.

I have a custom `ListAdapter` that sets the `ListView` rows from the database info. Each list row has an `ImageView`. I also have a small stylized dot image in the `drawable` folders for each color. I need to generate one image 6 sub-images wide, drawing each given dot side-by-side, in the given order. How can I generate an image on the fly and assign to the `ImageView`? Is it possible to check the cache path to see if its been generated and return it or else generate the image, save it to the cache path and then return it? Cacheing would work well since each user tends to gravitate to certain combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the getView method of your ListAdapter.

```
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item) {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final TextView row = (TextView) super.getView(position,
                    convertView, parent);

            String[] values = row.getText().toString().split(" ");
            Integer rowColor = Color.rgb(Integer.parseInt(values[0]),
                    Integer.parseInt(values[1]),
                    Integer.parseInt(values[2]));

            row.setBackgroundColor(rowColor);

            return row;
        }

    };
```

Comment: THen you could use whatever logic to set colors to 6 Layout views side by side, setting their color on the fly randomly or however.

Comment: That just changes the background color of the row. I was trying to create a composite image of 1-6 sub-images, drawn side-by-side. Each sub-image being a pre-drawn dot image.